# Good book/resource to learn "effective" template programming in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I saw Scott Meyers' ["Effective C++"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) third edition book having a small section on "Template Programming".

Any other book/links containing information on "effective" usage of templates ?

Answer (score 10):

I like [Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315). I found it very well written and clear. Contains a few advanced topics.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Vandevoorde / Josuttis 'C++ Templates the Complete Guide' is very accessible.

Answer (score 4):

[C++ Templates - The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/).  Alexandrescu's Modern C++ Design is very good, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you're already familiar with templates.  It's also geared more to C++ Framework creators.

Answer (score 2):

I quite like C++ Template Metaprogramming by Abrahams and Gurtovoy.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Meyers deals with the Standard Template Library in [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629). That may be relevant for you.

Answer (score 1):

A rarely mentioned but solid book is [C++ Common Knowledge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321321928) by Stephen C. Dewhurst. "Among the first users of C++ at Bell Labs", Dewhurst gives the book a somewhat deceptive title because he actually covers quite a bit of advanced material in particular in regards to templates.

Dewhurst's book is organized similarly to Meyers's with 63 "Items" that you can usefully read on their own. On templates you should look over items 45-59 (about 70 pages of reading).

[image]